# Excel 2013, obtaining the "app catalog"

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-addins, office-js, office-app

I am currently trying to install the free app called "People Graph" (https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Apps/tree/master/PeopleGraph). However, when I go to INSERT -­> APPS, it does not show any app catalog and when I try to add one from the confidentiality options I see that I need to put a URL for this.

Does anyone know what the URL is?

It is important to note that I am currently logged in into the MS account (which is a requirement for installing apps).

Currently working on compiling the source code of PeopleGraph gotten from GitHub so the executable can be imported directly into Excel.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the Insert Ribbon and open the My Add-ins dialog, navigate to "STORE" and search for the People Graph app, which is publicly available.

Alternatively if you want to deploy via a company catalog, then you'll need a SharePoint server that your client is configured to connect to (Configured via File-Option-Trust Center-Trusted Add-in Catalogs) and then it will show up under "My Organization" within the dialog.

Or if you are trying to debug it, then follow the instructions at the readme of the GitHub project and launch the app from Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Philip. When I do that it stills asks me for a catalog. 

If I go to the online STORE, then it allows me to add PeopleGraph and it now says I have it but it still does not show in "My apps".

Comment: @rockamic Check if you logged into Office (Your login shows on the top right of Word/Excel/PowerPoint..), I'm not entirely sure if apps will persist in the My Apps if you are not logged in.

Comment: Thank you, Philip. I am/was logged in. I just discovered this is an IT permission issue inside the company. I will confirm if that is what solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the people graph add in present publicly then go to store option and search people graph in the search box and select it. Simple.[image]